# Optimizing a mask for weights instead of weights themselves

Tags: optimization, pytorch, masking, autograd

I’m trying to optimize a mask for each weight of a simple DNN without updating the weights directly. My goal is to find a mask than I can multiply to network weights and achieve the maximum accuracy. This mask is the same size of the weights and denotes a coefficient of each weight parameter. The code I implemented is as follows:

```
learning_rate = 1
num_iterations = 3

weights = list(model.parameters())
masks = [torch.rand_like(layer.data, requires_grad=True) for layer in model.parameters()]

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(masks, lr=learning_rate)
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

for _ in range(num_iterations):
    for x, y in self.test_loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        for idx, param in enumerate(model.parameters()):
            param = param * masks[idx]

        x = model(x)
        loss = criterion(x, y)

        loss.backward()

        print("mask", masks[-1].data)
        print("grad", masks[-1].grad)

        optimizer.step()

        with torch.no_grad():
            masks = [mask.clamp_(0.0, 1.0) for mask in masks]
```

I multiply the masks by the weights and then feed a data to the model. then backward the loss and since only masks are grad required, I expect it to calculate the gradients of masks. But this code gives “None” for all gradients of masks.
I’ve spent lots of time to resolve it but haven’t been successful yet.

Comment: What is `indicators`? Also `param = ...` is an out-of-place operation so it's assigning a new value to the local variable `param`, but not modifying the parameters of the model. You could try `param *= ...` to do in-place updates, but I would not be surprised if pytorch complains since you would be using an in-place op to modify a trainable parameter.

Comment: Sorry, indicators was another name for masks. I updated the code. Yeah it gives error that a leaf variable that requires grad is being used in an in-place operation.